# How to auto go to button click event in android

Tags: android

I have one button and one function. I want to call automaticlly onClick button event after I call this function. How to implement it in Android. Thank you?

```
public onClickButton(View v)
{
//Do something
}
public functionA()
{
 //call onClickButton event
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is call this function:

```
button.performClick();
```

[Source: Android Docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

In xml, in button tag apply the attribute `android:onClick="functionA"`

and inside `functionA(View view)` call `onClickButton();`

Comment: Congratz on reaching 1k :)

Comment: I am prefer this same +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public onClickButton(View v)
{
//Do something
}
public functionA()
{
 //call onClickButton event
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
 onClickButton(button);
}
```